# Dynamically setting a default select option in Pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I was wondering is it possible to set a default select option in pug dynamically without using JavaScript?
I am using Node.js + Express for my back-end and when I render a pug file, I also pass an object with data.
Here is the Node.js code:

```
var eventToEdit = {
  event_event: rows[0].event_event,
  event_day: rows[0].event_day,
  event_start: rows[0].event_start,
  event_end: rows[0].event_end,
  event_phone: rows[0].event_phone,
  event_location: rows[0].event_location,
  event_info: rows[0].event_info,
  event_url: rows[0].event_url
};
res.render('editEvent', eventToEdit);
```

In my pug (editEvent.pug), I have a form in which one of the tags is the select:

```
.form-group
 label(for='dayInput') Day of Week
 select#dayInput.form-control(name='day')
  option
   | Sunday
  option
   | Monday
  option
   | Tuesday
  option
   | Wednesday
  option
   | Thursday
  option
   | Friday
  option
   | Saturday
```

What I'm trying to do is to use `event_day` variable to set a default option in the select tag. However, the problem is I can't seem to figure out a way to do so without using JavaScript.

I was able to get it to work using JavaScript, but I am wondering if it is even possible to get it to work without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed's answer is correct. I wanted to add this equivalent (but much more concise) approach that uses a loop:

```
.form-group
  label(for='dayInput') Day of Week
  select#dayInput.form-control(name='day')
    each day in ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
      option(selected= event_day === day) #{day}
```